# What should we use JSON blank array or 404 error code in Rest full services

Tags: android, json, web-services, restful-url, android-webservice

I hit on a link that return me records in JSON array format from android mobile. If records count is zero(0) or user have no records, Then what should I prefer :
1. 404 error code.
2. Blank JSON array.

Is there any standard, then give me a link for that standard.

Answer (score 4):

It is not an error. user exists. go for Blank JSON array. display the error when there is no such user.

The [JSON](http://www.json.org) format standard doesn't include a criteria for your question. It's only for validating the format.

There is a case were you want to send the error message instead of the empty array. thats you want to show the user a message and this message is handled by the server.

Comment: I want to know that there is any standard for this situation or standard way to handle this situation. Which is better 404 or blank JSON array?

Comment: There is no such standard. It the logical thing to do based on your situation. I gave you an example for both.